# Count elements satisfying a condition of two rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, functional-programming, aggregate

```
data
A  B
1  1
5  1
3  6
5  3
3  1
```

1. How to apply functional programming to count the number of lines in which A[i]>A[i-1] and B[i]==B[i-1]
2. And how to print these lines?

They are different tasks. I know we can solve the second task first and then solve the task 1. But I am very curious in different ways of solution without a for/any_other loop.

The data structures can be used: Numpy, Pandas, list of lists.

Comment: Have you even attempted it?

Comment: `df[df['A'].diff().gt(0) & df['B'].diff().eq(0)]`

Comment: The biggest problem I cannot use np.apply_over_axes of df.apply because it works element-wise (as I understand). I couldn't find anything in the Internet. That is why I am trying to find a solution here

Comment: @QuangHoang this looks promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `numpy` you need to find differences and then compare values of new array:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(data).values
diff = np.diff(x, axis=0)
mask = np.logical_and(diff[:,0]>0, diff[:,1]==0)

>>> mask
array([ True, False, False, False])
```

You are able to solve both of problems now:

- count the number of lines in which `A[i]>A[i-1]` and `B[i]==B[i-1]`:

  ```
  >>> np.sum(mask)
  1
  ```
- print these lines:

  ```
  >>> x[np.r_[False, mask]]
  array([[5, 1]])
  ```